# Limit the number of lines in a stacked label using python parser in ArcMap labels

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, labeling, python-parser

I am labeling names of places by stacking the labels at each space using the python code below. This makes some incoherent labels for text with many spaces and short or abbreviated words.

```
def FindLabel ( [Label] ):
 S = [Label]
 S = S.replace(' ', '\n')
 return S
```

I would like to limit the number of stacked lines that are allowed in each label (probably only 2 or 3).

I got it to work fine using the vb code below but due to a linux server it seems that only python will work for us in this case.

```
left( [Label]   ,instr((len( [Label] ))/2, [Label]  ," ")) & vbnewline & 
right( [Label]  ,len( [Label]  )-(instr((len( [Label] ))/2, [Label]  ," ")))
```

Is there a way to directly define the number of lines allowed using the python parser, or is it best to count the characters like the vb expression did?

Comment: You could get it to truncate to the first 3 lines with `"\n".join(S.split("\n")[:3])`